# How to connect a gsm modem AUTOMATICALLY to available COM ports (without combobox)

Tags: c#, combobox, port, gsm, modem

THIS QUESTION MAY SEAM A DUPLICATE, BUT NOT. after a long period of search on internet and no, result, then had to seek for assistance.

**All solutions apply to loading available ports in a combo box and the user checks one at a go. But the automation feature then dies.
thus, im looking for assistance on how the modem can connect automatically from the available ports without user interaction (USER FRIENDLINESS)**

FOR THE COMBO BOX, IT IS WORKING FINE AS BELOW,

```
using GsmComm.GsmCommunication;
using GsmComm.PduConverter;
using GsmComm.Server;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace COMM_All
{
    public partial class Comm_F : Form
    {
        public Comm_F()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
        }

        private void COM_PORTS()
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            txtGPort1.Items.AddRange(ports);
            txtGPort2.Items.AddRange(ports);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            COM_PORTS(); 
        }

        private void Modem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtGPort1.Text == "") { MessageBox.Show("Invalid Port Name"); return; }
            comm = new GsmCommMain(txtGPort1.Text, 9600, 8);
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

            bool retry;
            do
            {
                retry = false;
                try
                {
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor; comm.Open(); Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                    //MessageBox.Show("Modem Connected Sucessfully");
                     txtGStatus1.Text = "Connected Sucessfully";
                     comm.EnableMessageNotifications();
                     MessageBox.Show("Message notifications activated.");

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                    if (MessageBox.Show(this, "GSM Modem is not available", "Check",
                        MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Retry)
                        retry = true; 
                    else { return; }
                }
            } while (retry);
  
      }
}
}
```

*Note: Computer has multiple usb devices;*

Comment: What is a GsmCommMain object? It is from your code or it is some kind of library that you are using?

Comment: its from my code!  
`using GsmComm.GsmCommunication;
using GsmComm.PduConverter;
using GsmComm.Server;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace COMM_All
{
    public partial class Comm_F : Form
    {
        public Comm_F()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
        }
}
}
`